# como consumir dll delphi en c#

Tags: c#, delphi, pascal, delphi-2010

tengo una function de delphi que la exporto como dll, aqui dejo mi codigo:

```
library MdEncDec;

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  Bcrypt;

{$R *.res}

function EncryptWord( value: PChar ): ShortString; stdcall; export;
var
  BCRYPT1: TBCRYPT;
begin
  BCRYPT1 := TBCRYPT.create( nil );
  try
    BCRYPT1.AlphaMode := False;
    BCRYPT1.AlphaMode := True;
    BCRYPT1.Mode      := MODE_ENCRYPT;
    BCRYPT1.InString  := value;
    Result            := BCRYPT1.OutString;
  finally
    BCRYPT1.Free;
  end;
end;

function DecryptWord( value: PChar ): ShortString; stdcall; export;
var
  BCRYPT1: TBCRYPT;
begin
  BCRYPT1 := TBCRYPT.create( nil );
  try
    BCRYPT1.AlphaMode := False;
    BCRYPT1.AlphaMode := True;
    BCRYPT1.Mode      := MODE_DECRYPT;
    BCRYPT1.InString  := value;
    Result            := BCRYPT1.OutString;
  finally
    BCRYPT1.Free;
  end;
end;

exports EncryptWord, DecryptWord;

begin
end.
```

A la hora de consumirla en c# hice lo siguiente:

```
 [DllImport("MdEncDec.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention
 =CallingConvention.StdCall)]
 public static extern string 
 EncryptWord([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string cadena);

 Console.WriteLine(EncryptWord("Test"));
 Console.ReadLine();
```

Esto me da problemas no me muestra la cadena encriptada que es la function del delphi,al final no me muestra nada, ya compile la dll 32 y 64 bit en modo debug y release no se que mas hacer, si alguien tiene conocimientos acerca de esto y pudiera ayudarme, se lo agradeceria, llevo una semana en esto.

Gracias

Comment: `ShortString` es un tipo de dato que solo existe en _pascal_. No recomiendo su uso en DLL's que van a ser consumidas desde otros entornos, menos .NET. Diría que, de manera simple, utilices `AnsiString` o y aún así vas a tener el problema de quién reserva y quien libera la memoria. Es mejor recibir un puntero a un arreglo de caracteres, como un `PChar`, `PAnsiChar` o `PWideChar`, y que sea quién llama a esta rutina el responsable de reservar y liberar esta memoria.

Comment: No lo escribí como respuesta, porque no estoy seguro que sea el único problema que tienes y no tengo a mano lo necesario para probar por mi mismo, si me confirmas que te funciona, lo escribiré como una respuesta más elaborada. Un saludo.

Comment: Buen dia, tienes razon jachguate, en efecto usando los tipos de datos PWideChar o PChar y haciendo uso de los punteros, resolvi el problema, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Lo escribí como respuesta, hace casi 3 años... veo que nunca la aceptaste :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema reside en el uso del tipo de dato `ShortString` como tipo de salida de las funciones que estás exportando.

Esto se debe a que este es un tipo de dato que solo existe en pascal y que tiene un comportamiento particular.

A primera vista, para una prueba rápida, puedes sustituir los tipos de salida por `AnsiString` y aún así vas a tener el problema de quién reserva y quien libera la memoria.

Como solución definitiva, cambialo por un puntero a un arreglo de caracteres, como un `PChar`, `PAnsiChar` o `PWideChar`, y que sea quién llama a esta rutina el responsable de reservar y liberar esta memoria.

```
function EncryptWord(Value: PChar): PChar; stdcall; export;
```

## ¿Por qué no se recomienda su uso?

A manera informativa, los _detalles de implementación son que la posición `[0]` del arreglo, guarda la longitud de la cadena de caracteres (por lo que puede tener una longitud máxima de 255 caracteres), y la cadena no es terminada en `#0`.

Por esto mismo no se recomienda su uso en DLL's que van a ser consumidas desde otros entornos, menos .NET.

Técnicamente se podría utilizar, pero te verías obligado a implementar la lógica para manejar este tipo de cadenas en el lenguaje de tu elección. No es complicado pero, tampoco tiene sentido más allá de algún interés puramente académico.